# Forward GoDaddy URL to Google Sites

Tags: dns, website, url, forwarding, godaddy

I have a domain registered at GoDaddy, call it godaddyurl.com. I would like it to forward to a website I created through Google Sites, call it googlesites.com. I can't seem to do so. I would like the Google Sites pages to be displayed as godaddyurl.com, godaddyurl.com/..., etc. (For example, the URL googlesites.com/directory/page.html would be displayed as godaddyurl.com/directory/page.html.) I have tried a bunch of things, such as the following, but nothing works how I would like.

In GoDaddy DNS Management/Forwarding, I can forward it without masking to the site. This works, but when I do with masking, it doesn't work.

In the Google Sites, I have successfully added godaddyurl.com to the web addresses for the site, but this doesn't seem to do anything.

I think the probable correct solution will be to add/edit things like CNAME in the DNS. But I am not sure what to do. Any resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand right, you would like to forward the GoDaddy URL but keep it in the address bar, even though the display is coming from Google Sites.

You would find that any modern browser will make that impossible.
If it was possible then it would open the door to
[Phishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing)
attempts.

It is extremely important that the current website be displayed correctly
in the address bar together with all information relating to the website
reliability and certificate details.

In other words, this is impossible. You would need to host your pages on
GoDaddy to achieve that.
The most you can do is keep empty pages on GoDaddy that get their
content from Google Sites via
[Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).